# Strange exec and sp_executesql different behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small stored procedure (SQl Server 2012).

IF I run it using:

```
exec spSelRegion @bOver21 = 1
```

I Get different results than if I run it using:

```
  exec sp_executesql N'spSelRegion',N'@bOver21 bit',@bOver21=1
```

What is the difference?

```
 ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSelRegion]
    (
        @ID int = NULL
        ,@Name varchar(128) = NULL
        ,@OrderBy varchar(16) = 'ID'
        ,@bOver21 bit = null
    )
    AS 
    SELECT  distinct
        r.[ID],
        r.[Name],
        r.[dInserted],
        r.[sInserted],
        r.[dUpdated],
        r.[sUpdated],
        r.[timestamp]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[tblRegion] r
            left outer join tblCountyRegion cr
            on r.ID = cr.RegionNbr
    WHERE
        (r.[ID] = @ID or @ID is null) 
        AND (r.[Name] = @Name or @Name is null)
        AND (@bOver21 is null and r.[ID] >20
        OR (@bOver21 = 1 and r.[ID] > 20 and cr.IsActive=1) 
        OR (@bOver21 = 0 and r.[ID] >= 21 and r.id < 31))
```

I don't want to make this more complecated than it is . But after a microsoft update today , some stored procedures are now runnig using sp_executesql  instead of Exec and this is source of the issue.

Comment: What differences do you get?

Comment: What is the difference? Can you review sql profiler  to know the difference.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to run your dynamic SQL with the parameter specified.  Without that, it assumes a null value passed.  So this:

```
  exec sp_executesql N'spSelRegion @bOver21 = @bOver21',N'@bOver21 bit',@bOver21=1
```

Comment: This also returns no results. Something is different.

Comment: I just adjusted for your example and set it more explicitly.  Try again.